# Access 2007 VBA SQL Select Error "Item not found in this collection"

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

Returning after fixing errors and now a new one. I have created an SQL Statement using VBA in Access 2007 and I am getting the error "Item not found in this collection" The fields do exist in the tables and are spelled correctly. I even copied the SQL statement into a query and it worked. I'm assuming the error is with this part of the code

```vbs
Dim strCMCID As Long  ' (it's a Key field AutoNumber) 
strCMCID = Me!CMCID_Txt
```

and

```vbs
"WHERE Commitments_Tbl.CMCID = " & strCMCID & ""
```

Full code posted below. This is my first time putting an SQL Statement in using VBA. What I am trying to do is get the SQL Statement to pull two email addresses from a specific record from the current Form.

```vbs
Public Sub SendConfirm()
On Error GoTo Err_SendConfirm_Click

Dim Borrower As String, LOEmail As String, ProcEmail As String, ClsEmail As String, Caution As String, LNumber As Long, TheFile As String, TheName As String

'SQL Statement to get Processor and Closer email
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCMCID As Long  'AutoNumber
Dim strMWS As String
Dim strProcEM As String
Dim StrClsEM As String

strCMCID = Me!CMCID_Txt  'AutoNumber
strSQL = "SELECT Commitments_Tbl.CMCID, Status_Tbl.MWStatus, DBUsers_Tbl.EMail, DBUsers_Tbl_1.EMail " & _
"FROM ((Commitments_Tbl LEFT JOIN Status_Tbl ON Commitments_Tbl.LoanNumber = Status_Tbl.LoanNumber) LEFT JOIN DBUsers_Tbl AS DBUsers_Tbl_1 ON Status_Tbl.Processor = DBUsers_Tbl_1.MWName) LEFT JOIN DBUsers_Tbl ON Status_Tbl.Closer = DBUsers_Tbl.MWName " & _
"WHERE Commitments_Tbl.CMCID = " & strCMCID & ""

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
strMWS = rst!MWStatus
strProcEM = Nz(rst!DBUsers_Tbl.EMail, "John.Doe@CWork.com")
StrClsEM = Nz(rst!DBUsers_Tbl_1.EMail, "John.Doe@Work.com")

'Message Box
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response

LOEmail = Me!OrigID_Cbo.Column(3)
Borrower = Me!BorrNameL_Txt
LNumber = Nz(Me!LoanNumber_Txt, 0)

Msg = "Do you want to send an e-mail to Set_up?"
Style = vbYesNo
Title = "Cancel Set-Up E-Mail"
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
If Response = vbYes Then
    GoTo line3
Else
    GoTo line4
End If

line3:
TheName = "" & Borrower & " " & LNumber & ""
TheFile = "P:\mortgage\prodcenters\LOAN ITEMS (SW)\_RateLocks_and_Changes\" & TheName & ".rtf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Confirmation_Email2", acFormatRTF, TheFile, False

    If Nz(Me!InvestorID_Cbo, "Blank") = "Blank" Then
      DoCmd.SendObject , , , "CommerceMortgage@CommerceBank.com", , , "New Lock: " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, "A rate lock confirmation has been saved down to the server at P:\mortgage\prodcenters\LOAN ITEMS (SW)\_RateLocks_and_Changes as a word document with the same name and loan number as that is the subject line of this email. Please upload it into the GDR.", -1
    Else
      DoCmd.SendObject , , , "CommerceMortgage@CommerceBank.com", , , "Term Change" & ": " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, "A rate lock confirmation has been saved down to the server at P:\mortgage\prodcenters\LOAN ITEMS (SW)\_RateLocks_and_Changes as a word document with the same name and loan number as that is the subject line of this email. Please upload it into the GDR.", True
    End If

line4:
    ClsEmail = Nz(StrClsEM, "John.Doe@Work.com")
    ProcEmail = Nz(strProcEM, "John.Doe@Work.com")
If Me!RateExpDate_Txt <= Date + 8 Then
    Caution = "STOP Terms Finalized:"
ElseIf strMWS = "Closing" And Me!RateExpDate_Txt >= Date + 8 Then
    Caution = "STOP:"
Else
    Caution = ""
End If
If Me!InvestorID_Cbo = "" Then
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Confirmation_Email", "SnapshotFormat(*.snp)", LOEmail, ProcEmail & ";" & ClsEmail, , Caution & "New Lock: " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, , True
Else
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Confirmation_Email", "SnapshotFormat(*.snp)", LOEmail, ProcEmail & ";" & ClsEmail, , Caution & "  " & "Term Change" & ": " & Borrower & ": " & LNumber, , True
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

Exit_SendConfirm_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_SendConfirm_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_SendConfirm_Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we create a query in Access that pulls two fields with the same name from two different tables then Access will name the resulting columns `Table1.Field` and `Table2.Field` to disambiguate. When referring to those fields in the Recordset using "bang (`!`) notation" you must put square brackets around the entire field name. In your case, for example, you would need to use

```vbs
rst![DBUsers_Tbl.EMail]
```

instead of

```vbs
rst!DBUsers_Tbl.EMail
```